# Can I merge content of one site to another without redirect

Tags: website, blogging

I have a website `http://www.pulpybucket.com`

I want to merge (completely transfer) content of my other website into this.. Is there any way to do this with redirection.. and without hurting my website?

Comment: Move the files from one host or domain to the other? And then set up links to access it from existing pages?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like an iframe redirect (below), but agree with Raystafarian that it is best just to FTP the files from one server to the other.

```
<html><body><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%"
src="http://www.pulpybucket.com" name="redirect" id="redirect">
<p>IFrames are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe><br />
</body></html>
```